# Augmented Reality in React-Native

Tags: react-native, augmented-reality

It is a question to professional developers at react-native. My react-native application needs augmented reality in it to develop complex games. I tried using `viro-react`, if you know this package. Developers of `viro-react` gave up on the package:

1. Not supported on IOS anymore
2. Documentation for some components is missing or poor

Are here people who is successfully using AR in their apps? Can you please tell me how you are doing it (different package or native components)? If it is native components, can you please tell me in a nut shell how to use native components with AR?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viro is actually a company that no longer exists, so don't hold your breath waiting for them. You can try using [this example](https://github.com/echoARxyz/ReactNative-Viro-echoAR-example) that works on both Android and iOS if you really want to use viro.
From my experience, there is no great solution to building AR apps in react native. You can also build the AR part of your app in Unity and import it into your app using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-unity-view).

Comment: Hello @bpedazur, thank you for the reply. Do you know if native components with AR work in react-native? Have you ever tried doing so?

Comment: From my experience, there is no good enough tool for building AR/VR apps n react-native. I don't know of any companies that use react-native for their AR apps, I do know of individuals who tried to do it, but were not happy with the results (myself included). If you like building in react-native I would really recommend building the AR part in Unity-3D and importing it into your app. If you use echoAR, it'll also be very easy for you to manage your assets and save a lot of storage space.

Comment: Thank you @bpedazur. Did you use react-native-unity-view? There are many forks of this package. May you sure what fork you used or did you use the main one?
I am thinking of using this fork https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-unity-view-reinvented because it looks like that the main one is not maintained anymore.

Comment: @dontdownvoteme I am integrating Unity into react-native with AR

Comment: @Danny711 i think I will do the same